# How to set a second variable for Apcahe eCharts detail.formatter?

Tags: echarts

My data lives inside a variable named `gaugeData`. And it has two properties `value` and `date`.

And in Apache eCharts I am trying to use `detail.formatter` to create two headings with different text styles, like this:

`formatter: ['{header|{value}}', '{subHeader|{date}}'].join('\n')`

The first header displays the `value`, and the second subHeader displays the `date`.

Currently, the `value` is displaying correctly but the `date` is not.

Here is a screenshot of how it looks:

[image]

How do I make the `date` also work as a variable?

I don't care if `date` lives outside the `gaugeData`, I just need it to be a variable of some kind.

Here is my full code:

```JavaScript
const gaugeData = [
  {
    value: 80,
    date: '15-30-2022',
  },
];

const gaugeOption = {
  series: [
    {
      data: gaugeData,
      type: 'gauge',
      startAngle: 180,
      endAngle: 0,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      splitNumber: 3,
      pointer: {
        icon: 'circle',
        length: '12%',
        width: 50,
        offsetCenter: [0, '-90%'],
        itemStyle: {
          color: '#FFFFFF',
          borderColor: borderColor,
          borderWidth: 5,
          shadowColor: 'rgba(10, 31, 68, 0.5)',
          shadowBlur: 1,
          shadowOffsetY: 1,
        },
      },
      axisLine: {
        show: true,
        roundCap: true,
        lineStyle: {
          width: 9,
          color: [
            [0.5, '#e76262'],
            [0.54],
            [0.66, '#f9cf4a'],
            [0.7],
            [0.83, '#eca336'],
            [0.87],
            [1, '#3ece80'],
          ],
        },
      },
      axisTick: {
        length: 2,
        lineStyle: {
          color: '#8a94a6',
          width: 2,
        },
      },
      splitLine: {
        show: false,
      },
      axisLabel: {
        show: false,
      },
      title: {
        show: false,
      },
      detail: {
        rich: {
          header: {
            fontSize: 36,
            fontWeight: 700,
            fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
            color: '#0a1f44',
          },
          subHeader: {
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: 400,
            fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
            color: '#8a94a6',
          },
        },
        formatter: ['{header|{value}}', '{subHeader|{date}}'].join('\n'),
        offsetCenter: [0, '-20%'],
        valueAnimation: true,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The `formatter` can take a callback function where you can reference any other variable you like.

So when using Vue my data variables can look like this:

```
const scoreDate = ref('15-30-2022');
const scoreValue = ref(80);

const gaugeData = [
  {
    value: scoreValue.value,
  },
];
```

And the `formatter` property of the options object looks like this:

```
        formatter: function (data: number) {
          return `{header|${data}} \n {subHeader|${scoreDate.value}}`;
        },
```